# Scroll down in the iframe element with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, mousewheel

I have a problem when I want to scrol [image: in this Iframe application], I attach the code from where I locate and change to the frame and how I currently try scrolling:

```
.
.
.
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id ="nivel4_11_5_3_1_2"]').click() # Consultar factura y nota
WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(('iframeApplication'))) #Cambiar a iframe consulta de facturas
for z in categories_1:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/div[2]/input')))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(periodoactual[0]) #Rellenar fecha inicio
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(periodoactual[1]) #Rellenar fecha final
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div/div[3]/input[1]').clear() #Limpiar campo de tipo de consulta
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div/div[3]/input[1]').send_keys('FE Recibidas') #Llenar con tipo de consultas
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span/span/span/span[3]').click() #Clickear en buscar comprobantes
    sleep(5)
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'iframeApplication')))
    marco= driver.find_element(By.ID,'iframeApplication')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"})', marco)
    print(len(driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT,'Descargar Factura (XML)')))
```

I want to highlight that the switch works correctly since I can retrieve information and click within the frame, what I want is scrolling down

The problem is the following: in order for it to load all the information from the iframe I need scrolling, that way the print count of elements returns 64 and not 25, that's why I want scrolling down into the iframe

Answer (score 0):

No need to switch.
Can you try following code:

```
marco= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dojox_grid__View_1"]/div')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"})', marco)
```

Comment: Doesn't work u.u, i will update my code indicating where I try to implement it